# Custom color my UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I would like to have my `UIActivityIndicatorView` be colored a custom color.  Is there any way to set this property?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

In iOS 5.0 and up you can use `setColor:` on the `UIActivityIndicatorView` to set a custom color.

In Swift you can just use `activityIndicatorView.color = UIColor.red`

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a custom set of images (better), then animate it using a UIImageView.

Or place a colored transparent view on top of the activity indicator to "tint" it (lower quality).

Comment: Hi kenny...its good idea but have you any sample code to rotational animation of UIImageView ?

Comment: @yakub: No. You create 10 images and use `animationImages`. At least that how the indicator views work.

Answer (score 2):

For Xcode 7 (possibly earlier) you can also specify the color directly in Interface Builder.